# What is the most optimal way to produce Pascal's Triangle in C

Tags: c

Pascal's Triangle in the C programming language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define X 15
int main(){
    int tri[X][X];
    for (int i=0;i<X;i++) {
        tri[i][0]=1;
        for(int k=X-1;k>i;k--) {
            tri[i][k]=0;
        }
        for(int j=1;j<i+1;j++) {
            tri[i][j]=tri[i-1][j-1]+tri[i-1][j];
        }
    }
//To give the correct values to all number set elements
    for (int m=0;m<X;m++) {
        printf("%d\t",tri[m][0]);
        for (int n=1;n<m+1;n++) {
            printf("%d\t",tri[m][n]);   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
//to print them
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect there's a better way to solve this program which uses less memory storage, and I'd like to find a better solution to this C program.

What is the most optimized way to output Pascal's Triangle in C?

Comment: Do you need the data or just the output?  If the latter, then you only need to store the previous row.  As a given row is symmetric you only need to store n+1/2 of the row.

Comment: Well, I need the data.

Comment: The only memory you use is for the the data.  You could use a smaller type than int (uint8_t, uin16_, uint32_t if you want to be fancy in a union).  The only other idea would be compress the data.  If you can wrap access to the data you could calculate it on demand and not store anything.

Comment: If you have working code that you want peer reviewed for improvements, your question belongs at [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I will be more careful next time.//
I just joined the community today.

Comment: You should spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works - it will make your experiences here much better.:-)

Comment: I've edited this question's title/body to be more focused and within the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: You're using just over half the entries in that array, because the array is a square and the data is a triangle. Furthermore, the triangle is symmetric. So you could easily reduce its size by 75%. But even though it's easy, it's not at all clear that it's worth the trouble. How big do you expect the triangle to be?

Comment: 67 rows is all you're going to get before the numbers start to overflow 64 bits. And a 67x67 array is tiny in comparison to the gigabytes of memory that a desktop computer has, so memory really shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: "Most optimlzed" in what way? I mean, for memory, for CPU time? How is the data used or stored? Optimized for how many rows of the triangle? How is for example execution time measured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers in rows of Pascal's triangle are binomial coefficients. You can calculate them independently for each row:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define X 15

int main(void)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < X; ++n)
    {
        int c = 1;
        for (int i = 1;; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d\t", c);
            if (i > n)
                break;
            c *= n - i + 1;
            c /= i;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself

Comment: Potential optimization: `c*=n-i+1`, the `+1` can be factored out by changing `int n = 0; n < X` to `int n = 1; n <= X` and `i > n` to `i >= n`

Comment: As someone who just started learning C language, I was shocked.

Comment: @Benjamin.H: If you think that is shocking, do not look at `int main(void) { for (int n = 0; n < X; printf("1\n"), ++n) for (int i = 1, c = 1; i <= n; c *= n-i+1, c /= i++) printf("%d\t", c); }`.

Comment: Uhh, thanks for your suggestion.Now I can see why.......